# Is there an octonionic analog of the K3 surface, with implications for stable homotopy groups of spheres?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, k3-surfaces, octonions, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

The infamous K3 surface has many constructions in many fields ranging from algebraic geometry to algebraic topology. Its many properties are well known. For this question I am really interested in the K3 surface from a algebraic topology perspective (hence I view it as a particular smooth 4-manifold).

As we have seen in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/44866/184), and [also this one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/201587/184), the K3 surface  plays an important role in the third stable homotopy group of spheres. It can be viewed as the source of the 24 in this group $\pi_3^{st} = \mathbb{Z}/24$. Here is a brief review of how that goes: the stable homotopy groups (in degree n) of spheres are the same as cobordism classes of stably framed manifolds (of dimension n). In dimension three the generator is given by $\nu = (S^3, \text{Lie})$, the 3-sphere with its Lie group framing (where we think of $S^3 \subseteq \mathbb{H}$ as the group of unit quaterions).

The K3 surface is responsible for the relation $24 \nu = 0$ which comes from the existence of a certain framed 4-manifold whose boundary is a disjoint union of 24 copies of the framed 3-sphere $\nu$. The two important properties of the K3 surface which give rise to this are:

1. The K3 surface is an example of an almost hyperkahler manifold, which means that its tangent bundle admits a reduction to an $S^3 = SU(2)$ vector bundle. In fact it is integrable (so a hyperkahler manifold), but that is not important for this. What is important is that it admits three different complex structures $I,J$ and $K$ which generate a quaterionic algebra. This means that given a vector field $v$ on the K3 surface we get a quadruple of vector fields 
   $$(v, Iv, Jv, Kv)$$ 
   which form a frame whereever $v$ is non-zero.
2. The Euler characteristic of the K3 surface, the obstruction to the existence of a non-vanishing vector field, is 24.

This means that if we cut out 24 small balls from the K3 surface, we get a manifold $X$ with boundary $\partial X = \sqcup_{24} S^3$, 24 copies of the 3-sphere. $\chi(X)= 0$, and so $X$ admits a non-vanishing vector field, which restricts to the inward pointing normal vector field at each boundary component. 
Using the hyperkahler structure this gives us an (unstable) framing of $X$ which restricts to the Lie group framing at each of the boundary 3-spheres. Hence $24 \nu = 0$.

What I would like to understand is if there is an analog of this story which replaces the quaternions with the octonions?

The $\pi_7^{st} = \mathbb{Z}/240$ and is generated by the framed 7-sphere $\sigma$ which is $S^7$ with its "Lie group framing" coming from its embedding as the unit octonions $S^7 \subseteq \mathbb{O}$. It is not actually a Lie group, because the multiplication is non-associative, but there is still enough structure to obtain a framing (by, say, left-invariant vectors), and it is the generator.

I am wondering if there is an octonionic analog of the K3 surface which, in a similar way, leads us to the conclusion $240 \sigma = 0$? In other words I am looking for a smooth 8-manifold such that:

1. Its tangent bundle admits a multiplication by the octonions, in the same way K3's tangent bundle admits a multiplication by the quaternions. In particular given a vector field $v$ we should get an octuple:
   $$(v, Iv, Jv, Kv, Ev, IEv, JEv, KEv)$$
   which is a frame wherever $v$ is non-zero; and
2. The Euler characteristic should be 240.

Is there such a manifold? and how can we construct it? Does this sort of octonionic multiplication on the tangent bundle have a name? If there isn't such a manifold is there perhaps some replacement which still allows us to see, geometrically, that $240 \sigma = 0$?

Comment: If $I,J,K,E,IE,JE,KE$ are maps from the tangent bundle to itself than their multiplication is necessarily associative.

Comment: @WillSawin Maybe one could utilize triality setup - there are three 8-dimensional spaces (presumably the tangent, "left" half-spinors and "right" half-spinors) with actions of these $I$, $J$, $K$, etc. jumping between them in such a way that it is impossible to come up with a compatible choice of a single system of isomorphisms between these three spaces which would produce associative actions. I realize this is more than vague, I just want to throw into the discussion the triality thing somehow :D

Comment: The Octionions $\mathbb{O}$, viewed as an 8-manifold, admit the kind of structure I have in mind, as does the 8-torus $T^8 = \mathbb{O}/ \Lambda$, or any (unstably) framed 8-manifold. Also the tautological rank eight bundle on $\mathbb{OP}^1 = S^8$ is also a vector bundle with this sort of structure. They are associated to "$GL_1(\mathbb{O})$-principal bundles" where $GL_1(\mathbb{O})$ is a "non-associative Lie group". This makes sense since each of these bundles admits a trivialization over a cover with no non-trivial triple intersections (so associativity doesn't factor into it).

Comment: Can you do a kummer-esque construction to the 8-torus and get anything nice?

Comment: Probably you are already aware of all this, but this book review written by John Baez contains a lot of interesting numerology that suggests an interesting answer to your question. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/conway_smith/

Comment: In particular, the number 24 appears as the kissing number of the most dense lattice in 4-d. This 24 is surely the same 24, but I haven't thought enough about it to tell a coherent story (maybe such a story involves the binary tetrahedral group). Similarly 240 is the corresponding kissing number for a lattice in 8 dimensions...

Comment: @DylanWilson I thought about that a little. If we just proceed naively and take the abelian group $T^8$ modulo $a \mapsto -a$ then we get a singular (orbifold) quotient with $2^8 = 256$ singular points. If we cut out balls in a neighborhood of each of these points we get a space $W$ with $\chi(W) = -256/2 = -128$ and $\partial W =$ 256 copies of $\mathbb{RP}^7$. I am not sure how to resolve the singularities. We must choose a manifold $Y$ with boundary  $\mathbb{RP}^7$. Let $y = \chi(Y)$ be its Euler characteristic. (cont)

Comment: Then if we blow up those 256 points using $Y$, we get a manifold $M$ with $\chi(M) = 256 y - 128$. But then 240 is not an integer solution to this equation. So any Kummer-esque construction is going to have to be more involved.

Comment: Someone should mention G_2 manifolds at some point, surely...

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries someone should do the Kummer approach without doing blowup, in the sense of working with the underlying differentiable stack of the orbifold (maybe this doesn't work! But I feel that it should). Then one could see how your case should work. Possibly one needs to work with a 2-stack rather than just a naive orbifold (for instance, the quotient of the torus by the action of a 2-group, for instance the nontrivial symmetric 2-group structure on $(\mathbb{Z}/2)//(\mathbb{Z}/2)$).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, such M exists.  The boundary connected sum of 28 copies of the Milnor plumbing has boundary diffeomorphic to $S^7$ so it can be closed off with $D^8$ and you can let $M$ be the connected sum of the resulting closed manifold and <strike>8 copies</strike> 7 copies of $S^4 \times S^4$.

Why does that work?  Let $f: M \to \mathbb{O}P^1 = S^8$ have degree 240 and let $L$ denote the canonical bundle over $\mathbb{O}P^1$ whose euler class generates $H^8(S^8;\mathbb{Z})$.  Since $M$ has signature $28 \cdot 8 = 224$ and since $$\mathcal{L}_2 = \frac{7}{45}p_2 = \frac{42}{45}e \in H^8(\mathbb{O}P^1;\mathbb{Q})$$ we see from the signature formula that $p_2(f^*(L)) = p_2(TM)$ from which we deduce that $TM$ and $f^*(L)$ are stably isomorphic (they are both stably trivial away from the top cell of $M$ so $p_2$ is the only obstruction).  Since the two bundle have the same euler class we deduce that they are also unstably isomorphic, i.e. $$f^*(L) \cong TM,$$ which should give the bundle condition you're looking for.

Remark: Maybe it follows from the results in Kreck's paper "Surgery and duality" that up to diffeomorphism this is the only possible 3-connected $M$ which is parallelizable away from a point.  (**EDIT:** No, see [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218549/finding-the-octonionic-analog-of-the-k3-surface-via-almost-hyperkahler-geomet?lq=1#comment538602_218549).)

Comment: This is really really great, thank you! I have lots of questions. When you say the Milnor pluming, I take it you mean the pluming on the $E_8$-graph, yes? I am confused about two points. The first is: did you really mean 8 copies of $S^4 \times S^4$? or did you mean 7 copies? When I tried to compute the Euler characteristic of M I am off by 2, which could mean I made an arithmetic mistake, or that we really want 7 copies. More importantly, I see how the argument works if we know that $p_1(TM) = 0$. Can you remind me how we can see that?

Comment: Also for others who might read this and be confused like I was, one key point is that for this bundle L on $\mathbb{OP}^2$, we have $e(L)$ is the generator but $p_2(L) = 6 e(L)$. This follows from the calculation that the map $S^8 \to BSO$ which is the generator in $\pi_8$ induces multiplication by 6 in cohomology (generated by $p_2$ on the RHS). This is also why on String manifolds there is a $p_2/6$ class.

Comment: ( I meant $L$ is a bundle on $\mathbb{OP}^1$, not $\mathbb{OP}^2$)

Comment: The plumbing should be of the $TS^4$ (disk bundle) so that the self intersection number of the S^4 is 2 (or -2) to get the $E_8$ matrix. That should take care of $\chi$ now.

Comment: To see that $p_1(TM)$ is zero note that it is enough to check this on the obvious generators for the 4-dimensional homology (the $S^4$'s).  The tangent bundle of $M$ on these spheres is the sum of two copies of $TS^4$ and hence stably trivial so $p_1$ is zero. Nice question by the way.  It would be nice if there was a nicer answer.   Along this line there is Hirzebruch's question of 24-d manifold with an action of the Monster Group.

Comment: That is a great way to see that $p_1$ is trivial! Thanks @TomMrowka btw it was your beautiful answer on the linked MO question that got me thinking along these lines. I will accept this answer, but I still think it is 7 copies of $S^4 \times S^4$ that are needed. If I am doing things right the first half of the construction (the 28 Milnor plumbings + cap) has $\chi = 8 *28 + 2 = 226$ while the connect sum of 8 $S^4 \times S^4$s has $\chi = 8 *2 +2 = 18$. The connect sum of these two parts then has $\chi(M) = 226 + 18 - 2 = 242$. If you use 7 $S^4 \times S^4$s, you get 240 instead.

Comment: Yes, 7 sounds right now.

Comment: Indeed,  I scanned the previous discussion too quickly and conflated the two appearances of 8, the $E_8$ and the number of $S^4\times S^4$s.  Should indeed be 7.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a construction of this manifold that didn't require knowing a priori that $bP_8 = \mathbb{Z}/28$. I was hoping to use this manifold to prove that $240 \sigma = 0$, but since the computation that $bP_8 = \mathbb{Z}/28$ presupposes $\pi_7^{st} = \mathbb{Z}/240$, this is circular reasoning.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries can someone edit the above answer to make sure the 7 vs 8 issue is fixed, and importantly, clarified that it has been fixed?