# Explicit framed null bordism realizing $\eta\nu =0$ in stable homotopy group of spheres

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

There are many standard results in the stable homotopy group of spheres (or equivalently framed bordism groups), about which I would like to acquire better geometric understanding. For example I learned a lot from this MO question: [third stable homotopy group of spheres via geometry?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44866/third-stable-homotopy-group-of-spheres-via-geometry/58263)

I’d like to ask for another question. Let $\eta$ and $\nu$ be the generators of $\pi_1^{st}$ and $\pi_3^{st}$ (with $\eta^3=12\nu$), each generated by $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$ with Lie group framing. They satisfy $\eta\nu=0$, but how do I construct framed null bordism of $U(1) \times SU(2)$?